# For loop Python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am having trouble with a particular for loop in my code.The error I get is "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer,list found

My code is :

```
current_dir = os. getcwd()
target_dire = [os.listdir(current_dir)]
for dirs in target_dirs:
   if is.path.isdir(dirs):
       print dirs[0]

  else:
       pass
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry my phone messed up the code indentation

Comment: which line you get error

Comment: The if statement line.

Comment: print dir or check the type of dir

Answer (score 2):

`os#listdir` returns a list already. You do not need to wrap it again.

From the documentation:

`Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.`

[Source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

To apply this to your program the following code should fit your needs:

```
import os

for dir in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isdir(dir):
        print dir
```

Comment: By wrapping in `[]` you are creating a list of lists of dir entries. The for loop is iterating throughout the outermost list but dirs is just the second inner list. This will fix it.

Comment: Yes. That was intentional because if I don't do that it will print out the first letters of what is left in the list

Comment: @user3295821 Please clarify what you are trying to do for additional help.

Comment: That is happening because of `print dirs[0]`. Strings are just lists or characters in Python (ok technically not true but it's an easy way to reason about this code). Change it to `print dirs`.

Comment: It works if I give it a specific offset,but I want it to iterate the whole list.

Comment: @user3295821 You are addressing two separate issues. The first is the error. This is caused by wrapping `os.listdir` in a list. The second is printing out a single character. If I had to guess, I would say you want to remove the `[]` around `os.listdir` and remove the indexing (`[0]`), you have. But again, please describe your desired output. At this point, we are just guessing at what you want as you haven't described anything.

Comment: I want to search for all directories in the current directory. But since os.listdir also shows files,I have to sperate those files from the directories since I will only be working with the directories.

Comment: @user3295821 I think you are misunderstanding the for loop. You are not increasing some counter variable. Each iteration is returning the next item in the list. To demonstrate this to yourself, remove your if logic and insert `print dirs`. Note the content. Assuming everything else is the same, it will print out a list. Now, remove the square braces around `os.listdir` and rerun the code. It will now print each item in the directory, one at a time. I've explained how to fix your program in a previous comment, but doing the exercise I describe will be likely be useful to you as well.